# After upgrading from Xcode 4.3 to Xcode 4.4 one of .xib file is not loaded

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface, builder

I have one .xib is not loaded after upgraded from 4.3 to 4.4. I tried to change developement target to 4.4 from interface builder --->file inspector but same. I have another Mac with Xcode 4.3 same project works fine there.

[image: interface builder xcode 4.4]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was not a problem with version of Xcode. Seems like Xcode 4.3 and earlier versions do not care about @synthesize in .m files once i put @synthesize in .m file my .xib file successfully loaded.